# How to backup MySQL database using Query?

Tags: mysql, database

How can we backup MySQL database using Query, like we can backup MS-SQL using following Query.

**Query:**

```
backup database DATABASENAME to disk = 'PATH'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mysqldump-php a pure-PHP solution to replicate the function of the mysqldump

```
 <?php
    require('database_connection.php');
    require('mysql-dump.php')
    $dumpSettings = array(
        'include-tables' => array('table1', 'table2'),
        'exclude-tables' => array('table3', 'table4'),
        'compress' => CompressMethod::GZIP, /* CompressMethod::[GZIP, BZIP2, NONE] */
        'no-data' => false,            
        'add-drop-table' => false,      
        'single-transaction' => true,   
        'lock-tables' => false,        
        'add-locks' => true,            
        'extended-insert' => true      
    );

    $dump = new MySQLDump('database','database_user','database_pass','localhost', $dumpSettings);
    $dump->start('forum_dump.sql.gz');
        ?>
```

also visit this link [GitHub](https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation for [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)

> The mysqldump client utility performs logical backups, producing a set of SQL statements that can be executed to reproduce the original database object definitions and table data.
>
> It dumps one or more MySQL databases for backup or transfer to another SQL server. The mysqldump command can also generate output in CSV, other delimited text, or XML format.

As noted by [Havenard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156811/havenard) it is already installed with MySQL Server and MariaDB, and is considered the official way of backing up a database.

Comment: Additional note: mysqldump is already installed with MySQL Server, it is the official way of backing up databases and requires you to install nothing else.