# is it possible to export MySQL database by executing a query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to add an option for my client in order to backup the data,so i am confused if there's a query can export the database instead of doing it manually from the phpMyAdmin. I am using php as a server-side language

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/back-up-your-mysql-databases/

Comment: i think that problem is already solved [Visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849196/how-to-backup-mysql-database-using-query)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to backup MySQL database using Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849196/how-to-backup-mysql-database-using-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like so and replace `[user]`, `[password]` and `[data-base-name]`

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p [password] [data-base-name] > myDBDumpFileName.sql
```

Read here for more information [Dumping Data in SQL Format with mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html)

You can also dump single tables from the database like so:

```
 mysqldump -u user -p password data-base table1 table2 table5 > myDBDumpFileName.sql
```

Then to make it run automatically I recomend setting up a cronjob which then calls a shell script, but you can also setup the cronjob calling a PHP script. [See here for more information on how to setup the cronjob](https://askubuntu.com/a/350892/383106)

Comment: I would recommend to use a tool like this https://github.com/2createStudio/shuttle-export

Comment: @C4pt4inC4nn4bis I would not recommend using a tool like that cause all you need is two things like mysqldump and cronjob. In my opinion there is no reason to dig trough code to accomplish such simple task.

Comment: I get your point and it is good to know how to achieve it by writing everything yourself. But on the other hand you only have to include one file and copy & paste the example. Comes along with compression and error handling. So it depends how much time someone is willing to invest for that problem. I personaly got no problem with including some external lib or script to quickly move on to other tasks.

Comment: this works but downloading the file zero KB, so i tried to run the command on the cmd prompt, i found that it require a password, when i write the password and press enter, the database exported successfully? do you know how to handle this?

Comment: @AlyAlAmeen well you obviously need the right passwords at the right places. Say the script creating the dump is already on the server might only need the DB password. You need to try step by step. Create the command until it works. Then put it in a file and make it a script, call it until it works. Then setup the cronjob until it works. Then maybe get the file via SSH, write the command until it works.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need

```
<?php
   $dbhost = 'enter_host_adress';
   $dbuser = 'DB_user_name';
   $dbpass = 'password';

   $backup_file = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
   $command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass ". "test_db | gzip > $backup_file";

   system($command);
?>
```

Comment: this works but downloading the file zero KB, so i tried to run the command on the cmd prompt, i found that it require a password, when i write the password and press enter, the database exported successfully? do you know how to handle this?